# SharePoint SQL Reporting

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, bcs, sql-server, reporting-services

how can I do a simple **report** on SharePoint 13? (reading data by a *SQL Server*).
Is there a way to put the data directly into a list? 
I heard about BDC how does it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Reporting Services on SharePoint 2013 is a complex arrangement that also depends upon the version of SQL Server (2008/2012/2014).
Reporting Services needs to be configured for the SharePoint integrated mode.

Some links to get you started -

Reporting Services with SharePoint Integration (TechNet)
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210649(v=sql.105).aspx

Installing and configuring SQL Reporting services on SharePoint 2013 (MSDN blog post)
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/biblog/archive/2012/12/04/installing-and-configuring-sql-reporting-services-on-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Reporting Services SharePoint Mode Installation (MSDN)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281311.aspx

SharePoint Business Connectivity Services (BCS) brings external data into the SharePoint farm and is also bidirectional (two-way) in which it can also update the external source. Whereas, the prior version BDC (Business Data Connectivity) would only bring in data.

Few links on SharePoint BCS -

Overview of Business Connectivity Services in SharePoint 2013 (TechNet): 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee661740(v=office.15).aspx

SharePoint 2013: Business Connectivity Services (BCS) improvements – Introduction (comprehensive blog series): 
http://zimmergren.net/technical/sharepoint-2013-business-connectivity-services-bcs-improvements-introduction

Answer (score 1):

BCS is the answer.

**Creating an External Content Type**

1. Open the Site in SharePoint Designer
2. From left navigation click on External Content Types
3. Now on the Ribbon you can see "External Content Type". Click on that to create a new ECT
4. Provide a name, namespace
5. To specify the SQL Server database for the external content type, click Click here to discover external data sources and define operations.
6. Click Add Connection, select SQL Server in the External Data Source Type Selection dialog box, and then click OK.
7. In the SQL Server Connection dialog box, enter the name of the server, the database name, an optional description, and then click OK.
8. Choose authentication mode = Connect with User’s Identity
9. In the Data Source Explorer, expand the database to view the tables, views, and routines that it contains.
10. Select a table.
11. In the Data Source Explorer, right-click the table, view, or routine, and then select "Create All Operations"
12. Click Next
13. Now ECT is ready

**Creating External List**

1. Open Site in Internet Explorer
2. On the Settings menu  Settings button, click View All Site Content, and then click Create .
3. Under the Filter By category, click Lists, click External List, and then click Create.
4. Type the Name for the list. Name is required.
5. Type the Description for the list. Description is optional.
6. To add a link to the Quick Launch, verify that Yes is selected in the Navigation section.
7. In the Data source configuration section, choose the External Content Type to use as the data source for this external list by
8. Click Select External Content Type.
9. Click Create.

Comment: Thanks, nice idea, but i preferred the Reporting Services Integration